# How to make this foreach loop work?

Tags: perl

I have Written a small code to subtract a specific number(499 here) from every line of my `test.dat` file. But this is not working. Input contains a number in every line. Please help me

```
open (F1, "test.dat" );


foreach $line (F1)
 {  
    $x = 0; 
    $x = $line-(499);
    print $x;
    $x = 0;              
}
```

Comment: could you post a snippet of test.dat

Comment: test.dat `139
448
711
315
696
983
784
`One number per line

Comment: @VAR121 But you said you have `499` in every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is subtract 499 from each line, I would simply do:

```
perl -plwe '$_ -= 499' input.txt > output.txt
```

Which is the equivalent of the program file:

```
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $_ -= 499;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

It will work as expected, assuming your data is consistent. It will not be able to handle non-numeric lines, and will produce warnings for any such lines, but also create a false `-499` value for such a line.

As a simplistic fix for such a problem, you can skip lines that do not contain the expected digits, but then the added problem is what kind of numbers are in your data. With only 0-9 integers, you will get away with:

```
next unless /^\d+$/;
```

For floating point numbers:

```
next unless /^[\d.]+$/;
```

For scientific notation, something more complicated, but perhaps we need not go that far.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few different errors there.  Rather than just tell you what they are, how about you start with a smaller piece.  Create a script that just reads test.dat and prints out each line that it reads.  Start your script with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, and declare your variables (e.g. `foreach my $line (...`)

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems with your code: -

- First you should use `3-arg open` to open a file
- Rather than using `bare` words, you should use `lexical variables` for your `file handle`
- And in your foreach loop you need to enclose your file handle in `<>`

First 2 are conventions, but the last one is a logical error

So, here's the change you need to do: -

```
open my $fh, '<', 'test.dat' or die 'Cannot open file:, $!';

foreach (<$fh>) {

    # $_ is the default special variable that holds the current element in loop
    # You can process $_ and subtract `499` from it and print it.
}
```

Comment: You could also write `open my $fh, '<', 'test.dat' or die ...;`

Answer (score -1):

Since the major phrase in your question is to make your foreach loop to process your dat file ,Below is the correct way of processing line by line and replace it with a blank string ( assuming thats what you are trying to achieve )

```
$DATFILE = test.dat; 

open(DATFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
foreach $line (<DATFILE>) {

    # do line-by-line processing. some what like this 
   if($line =~ /499/g) {

       $line  =~ s/499//g ;

   }

}
```

Comment: This will replace 499 from every where. Even from the middle of a number - `3549955`

Comment: @Rohit Jain , But the post comment there says each line has 499 string only or  other string like 535 343 424 etc thats y I posted this

Comment: Yeah you are right. But you should replace only `499` not `34992`. `/499/` will match even inside `34992`. Replace your regex with: - `\b499\b`

Comment: @RohitJain  Okay I got it , I missed /g there Thanks for correcting it

Comment: I believe the question meant to say *subtract* 499, not delete it.

Comment: What actually the Post means if he says substract I thought it is  replace little confusing , The post really needs a good edit @ysth

Comment: I meant to subtract not delete. I am really sorry.